# Filtering Rows in R Data Frame Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a data frame in R with three columns: Gene.ID, source, and value. I need to filter the rows based on multiple conditions, but I'm having trouble achieving the desired result. Here's a sample of my data:
My goal is to:

Keep rows with the same Gene.ID and source.
For rows with the same Gene.ID but different source, I want to keep them only if the value is different from the previous row.
I've tried various approaches using dplyr and custom loops, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired filtering logic.

Can someone provide a solution or suggest an efficient way to filter this data frame based on these conditions?

Thank you for your assistance!

```
df <- data.frame(
  Gene.ID = c(
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7"
  ),
  HMMER = c(
    "SLH",
    "GT2",
    "GT2",
    "GH13+CBM41+CBM41+GH13"
  ),
  dbCAN_sub = c(
    "",
    "GT2",
    "GT2",
    "CBM41+GH13+CBM41+CBM41+CBM48+GH13"
  ),
  DIAMOND = c(
    "",
    "",
    "GT2",
    "CBM41+CBM48+GH13+GH13+GH11"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

my desired output will be as followes

```
df_output <- data.frame(
  Gene.ID = c(
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7",
    "NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7"
  ),
  combined = c(
    "SLH",
    "GT2",
    "GT2",
    "CBM41",
    "GH13",
    "CBM41",
    "CBM41",
    "CBM48"
    "GH13",
    "GH11"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I tried with this command But I didnt get, desired output

```
df_output <- df %>%
  separate_rows(., sep = "\\+") %>%
  gather(key = "source", value = " ", -Gene.ID) %>%
  filter(combined != "") %>%
  distinct(Gene.ID, combined)
```

Comment: (1) Is `separate_rows` actually doing anything for you? For me, it's doing nothing, and will likely have problems if you use it correctly since the fields to be separated have different lengths of values to separate. (2) `tidyr::gather` was superseded years ago, I strongly suggest you learn to use `tidyr::pivot_longer`, it is far more powerful. (3) Perhaps you should `pivot_longer` (or `gather`) and _then_ `separate`. (4) Why create a column with a name of `" "`? That seems like making future operations on it rather difficult.

Comment: (5) "previous row" is really fragile, since I don't know that reshaping is going to guarantee everything is in the order you expect.

Comment: Lastly, it might clear up a lot of questions if you included what the output should be here. (Providing it as a frame is incredibly helpful, even if you have to create it manually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working version following your approach replacing some of the `tidyr` functions with more recent versions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_longer_delim(HMMER, delim = "+") %>%
  tidyr::separate_longer_delim(dbCAN_sub, delim = "+") %>%
  tidyr::separate_longer_delim(DIAMOND, delim = "+")%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Gene.ID, values_to = "combined") %>%
  dplyr::select(Gene.ID, combined) %>%
  dplyr::filter(combined != "") %>%
  dplyr::distinct()


# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Gene.ID                 combined
  <chr>                   <chr>   
1 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_15 SLH     
2 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_17 GT2     
3 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_68 GT2     
4 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7  GH13    
5 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7  CBM41   
6 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7  CBM48   
7 NZ_JAHWGH010000001.1_7  GH11
```

Note that this might create very long intermediate dataframes if run with a larger initial dataframe, as the `separate_longer` steps create many rows with redundant content which are only dropped again at the end (in this example 4 -> 359 -> 7 rows). There is probably a more efficient way to do this for large dataset.

Comment: @Umar I answered to your provided code example and the expected output, but I've realized that the title and first paragraph of the question seem to describe a different data structure / question. If the answer is off topic I can delete it.

Comment: Thank you, but , it didnt meet the answer, I did it using loop, i was busy with my manuscript, after this, so I couldnt see your reply